# Chainsaw part ID

Tags: part-identification

My Stihl 024AV chainsaw broke, and Im not sure what the broken piece is called. A flat triangle-ish shaped piece of metal broke off of the piece shown in the image. The part is between the motor and the clutch. Can you identify the name of the part?

[image: Broken Chainsaw]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's part of the clutch itself. I found [this online](https://performanceoutdoorequipment.com/collections/stihl-024-026-260-chainsaw-parts/products/aftermarket-1121-160-2051-11211602051-clutch), but I'm not sure it matches up exactly, even though it is supposed to be for the 024 model Sthil saws.

Comment: Thanks, and yeah... I just realized the clutch pads sit inside this. The chainsaw is 30+ years old, so I'm not 100% if parts are still the same.

Comment: Parts don't have to be exactly the same as long as they work :o)